# Cucumber not running in parallel with Maven

Tags: maven, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to run my Cucumber tests with Selenium in parallel using Maven. **I tried maven surefire plugin and failsafe plugin and even old cucumber jvm parallel plugin.** I've got the same result. My tests run in sequence without parallelization.

I've tried to configure maven-surefire-plugin and then maven-failsafe-plugin. Nothing helps.

Here is my pom.xml file

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>2</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/RunnerTest.class</include>
                    </includes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0.jre8-preview</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

And here my configuration of failsafe plugin. But it disabled

```
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>acceptance-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rerunFailingTestsCount>1</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/RunnerTest.class</include>
                                <include>**/*IT.class</include>
                            </includes>
                            <forkCount>2</forkCount>
                            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                            <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                            <reportsDirectory>target</reportsDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And my Runner class

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/features",
        glue = "step_definitions",
        plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumberHtmlReport", "json:target/cucumber-report.json"},
        monochrome = true,
        strict = true
)
public class RunnerTest {

}
```

To run my tests in Maven I use this command:

```
mvn clean verify "-Dcucumber.options=--tags @Test-1,@Test-2" -Dbrowser=chrome
```

In addition I can say that I'm using static webDriver and Singleton class for handling properties. I have no idea how it can impact but it's FYI. I can provide code if required.

For now I'm looking to run my tests in forks because threads handling is another big deal.

Comment: U should look at this docs - https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/. The static webdriver will lead to problems.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps.

### Key Point :

- We shall not mix direct & transitive dependencies specially their versions! Doing so can cause unpredictable outcome.
- We do not  need to use cucumber-jvm-parallel or cucable plugin when cucumber  version is greater than or equal to  4.0.0.

### Cucumber Parallel Execution via JUnit

**First -** Update POM.xml with correct set of io.cucumber dependencies.

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**Point To Note Down -** There could be an issue like everything is ok but still tests do not execute in parallel and could be if your pom.xml is having direct/transitive dependency of testng. As testNG causes Surefire to ignore JUnit wrapper class. If you had testng dependency so remove the TestNG dependency or you can take a call to 2 define 2 execution - For TestNG & JUnit and disable one as per your need.

**Second -** Customize Runner class as per your framework need

```
package com.jacksparrow.automation.suite.runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features/functional/",
                     glue = {"com.jacksparrow.automation.steps_definitions.functional" },
                   plugin = { "pretty","json:target/cucumber-json/cucumber.json",
                            "junit:target/cucumber-reports/Cucumber.xml", "html:target/cucumber-reports"},
                   tags = { "@BAMS_Submitted_State_Guest_User" },
                   junit ={ "--step-notifications"},
                   strict = false,
                   dryRun = false,
               monochrome = true)

public class RunCukeTest {
}
```

**Third -** Implementing maven surefire plugin which would actually run tests in parallel

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>2</threadCount>
        <reuserForks>false</reuserForks>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*RunCukeTest.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Fourth -** Implement Hooks.java

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.After;

public class Hooks {

    @Before
    public void setUpScenario(String browser){
        //BaseSteps.getInstance().getBrowserInstantiation(browser); your browser setup method
    }
    @After
    public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario){
    // more code goes here  
    }
   }
```

Comment: The most important part being here that `threadCount` is used instead of `forkCount`. Surefire can't parallelize test classes across forks, only across threads.

Comment: Okay thank you so much @mpkorstanje again for sharing the valuable information and can you please guide if we add JUnit and TestNG dependencies together then Surefire does not excited tests in parallel as testNG causes Surefire to ignore JUnit wrapper class. What shall be solution for this. What do you suggest please.

Comment: Don't mix the two. Use `cucumber-testng` if you are using TestNG.

Comment: @TheSociety thank you for response and help! But I faced with the issue that I can't update a surefire plugin to version 3.0.0-M3. I've got the error. I guess it's because my Maven version os 3.0.4 and I'm limited by it.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project XXX: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test failed:
Unable to load the mojo 'test' (or one of its required components) from the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3'

Comment: What if to try run tests with TestNG? Without Maven?